# Getting information of subprocess execution to update a progress bar in django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, subprocess

I'm trying to do a loading page with a progress bar in my django app while a process is running in background.

This is my view:

```
def getor(request):
# get video
    var = Video.objects.order_by('id').last()
    v = '/home/myproject/media/'+ str(var)
# process
    p = subprocess.Popen("./process.sh %s" % (str(v)),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    return render(request, 'progressbar.html')
```

I have done the progress bar frontend part. 
How I can get this percentages generated by the execution of process.sh in my django view so that i can give it to my template for the evolution of the progress bar ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say that you have done the frontend part, does that mean that you have taken care of all the communication, using ajax and dynamically update your page? That is, you problem is limited to get the percentage output from `process.sh`?

Comment: @JohanL I think the problem is to get the percentage of the subprocess.By which way we can get the percentage of suprocess progress?  I'm also looking for the solution for this scenario. If we can get percentage then probably you can have an ajax call every second and update the progress bar template side.

Comment: @Aniket is right

Comment: OK, the percentage is clearly output from the script `process.sh`. Do you know anything about that script? Have you written it yourself or is it from some program or downloaded from somewhere? The solution to the problem depends a bit on how the script operates.

Comment: I am just using it, I didn' t do it myself. It takes a video filename as input and compute a watermark Shape for it and it generate it in a file.

Comment: @JohanL It also generates a log file having the total number of frames and the frame number computed simultanously While the process is running

Comment: Can you provide the script?

Comment: It s a library that i run with a command inside the script process.sh